# Colors and axis messed up in colorplot using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new in Python and my purpose to use it is mainly to plot graphs as I'm a MSc Student. I possess files in the format described below and I'm trying to make a proper Colormesh from this:

```
0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
-3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
-2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
-1 7 7 4 4 4 6 6
0 7 7 4 4 4 6 6
1 7 7 4 4 4 6 6
2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

`[0 1 2 3 4 5 6]` of the first row are values for the y axis of the plot, and `[-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3]` of the first column are values for the x values of the same plot. The first 0 is only for spacing.

So, I stored those values in variables:

```
data = [[ 0.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.]
        [-3.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
        [-2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
        [-1.  7.  7.  4.  4.  4.  6.  6.]
        [ 0.  7.  7.  4.  4.  4.  6.  6.]
        [ 1.  7.  7.  4.  4.  4.  6.  6.]
        [ 2.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
        [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]]

x = [-3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3]

y = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6] 

z =  [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
      [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
      [7. 7. 4. 4. 4. 6. 6.]
      [7. 7. 4. 4. 4. 6. 6.]
      [7. 7. 4. 4. 4. 6. 6.]
      [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]
      [3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3. 3.]]
```

and `z` are the numbers that I really want to plot.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm, ListedColormap
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
import numpy as np
# ------------- Input Data Files ------------- # 

data = np.loadtxt('my_colormesh_data0.dat')  # Load Data File

# ------ Transform Data into 2D Matrix ------- # 

x = data[1:,0]
y = data[0,1:]
z = data[1:,1:]  # Take colormesh values and store into matrix   

# ============ Plot Commands =================== #

colormap = ListedColormap(['#404040', '#FFEE00', '#00DC00', '#FF8000', '#9900FF', '#000000', '#FF0000']) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap = colormap, vmin = z.min(), vmax=colormap.N)

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and this colorplot is the result of the above code:

[image]

However it isn't the wanted output as the colors are messed up.

To further illustrate what is my goal, here is a picture summarizing the problem:

[image: Code Output]

I don't understand why the colors and axis are messed up in code output, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to rotate and flip the data stored in z.  for rotation numpy has rot90 [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html)    for flipping [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html) for your case before you pass z to pcolor do the following

```
temp = np.rot90(z,-1)
z = np.flipud(temp)
```

Comment: I was testing that when you posted. Actually it worked with rotation 1 instead of -1:

`z = data[1:,1:]`,                      
`z = np.rot90(z,1)`,                               
`z = np.flipud(z)`

Although this is working as I wanted, I'm looking for an option inside the function `pcolormesh()` but I couldn't find it.